# When using a variable as input to soup.find(), None is returned, but using an identical str value as input works

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the innertext of a certain tag by using the find method in Beautiful Soup. When I input a variable as an argument to the find, it returns None, but using a str input of identical text will return me the result I would like. Why could this be?

Here is the code snippet:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raceResults, 'html.parser')

racedetdict={
    "courseGoing": '{"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_condition"}',
    "raceDate" :  '"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName__date"',
    "courseName" : '{"class": re.compile("rp-raceTimeCourseName__name")}',
    "raceDistance" : '{"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_distance"}'
}


for key, val in racedetdict.items():
    print("")
    print(val)
    out1 =  soup.find(attrs={"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_condition"})
    print(out1.get_text().strip())
    out2 = soup.find(attrs=val)
    print("")
    print(out2.get_text().strip())
```

Output:

```
{"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_condition"}    
Standard To Slow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in GetRaceResults
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionay-based iteration isn’t in fact using identical value strings for `find()` - The values in `racedetdict` are strings, not dictionaries. Remove the quotes on the values and it should start working. So change

```
racedetdict={
    "courseGoing": '{"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_condition"}',
    "raceDate" :  '"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName__date"',
    "courseName" : '{"class": re.compile("rp-raceTimeCourseName__name")}',
    "raceDistance" : '{"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_distance"}'
}
```

To

```
racedetdict={
    "courseGoing": {"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_condition"},
    "raceDate" :  {"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName__date"},
    "courseName" : {"class": re.compile("rp-raceTimeCourseName__name")},
    "raceDistance" : {"class": "rp-raceTimeCourseName_distance"}
}
```

(Also had to add `{ }` around the value for ‘raceDate`)